# Debugging Grails Applications

Tags: grails

In ruy on rails in order to debug the application you could just call, "debugger", and 
it will start a debugger in the console. How is this approach possible in Grails? Especially in a .gsp file? I am using a simple text editor for my development, Sublime.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Debugging java is simply not possible in Sublime.You can use another debugger like [JDebugTools](http://www.debugtools.com/) or a full-featured IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans (but that breaks the whole point to have a lightweight IDE like Sublime, which is great for Java, if not for debugging purpose)

There exists a command-line debugging tool, [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) which can be used for very simple debugging purposes, and may be integrated as a build tool for Sublime (I don't think the result will be good though)

Debugging for Grails is done with the --debug switch as for recent versions, you can then attach a debugger to the session. GSP debugging, like JSP, needs a specific tooling as to be aware of compilation means, and you'd better switch to `IntelliJ Idea` or `[GGTS (Groovy/Grails Tool Suite)](http://spring.io/tools/ggts)` which provide both strong debugging capabilities